# Storing custom data types in Django

Tags: python, django, geospatial

I have a custom class (and possibly more soon), that I would like to neatly store on some of my models in Django.

The class roughly looks like so:

```
class BBOX(object):

    def __init__(self, min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y, srs_code, **kwargs):
        self.min_x = min_x
        self.max_x = max_x
        self.min_y = min_y
        self.max_y = max_y

        self._srs_code = get_srs_code(srs_code)

        self._srs_identifier = 'EPSG:{}'.format(self.srs_code)
        self._srs = SRS(self.srs_code)
```

The class has a great many properties and helper functions that we use for safe handling of bounding box objects in our geospatial based application. In code, we pass these around safely knowing they will be easy to use and interact nicely with the rest out our code. As a rule, we do not ever want to be working with a bounding box in our code that isn't represented by an instance of this class, except when we absolutely must pass a list or something similar (e.g. when we serialize the values to JSON, YAML, or something similar).

Several of our Django models have BBOX related values. Currently, these disparate models all must manually define the fields they need in order to represent a BBOX. For convenience we added some helper properties to some of them to transform to our object. For instance:

```
class Layer(PolymorphicModel):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    parent_layer = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)

    min_x = models.FloatField()
    min_y = models.FloatField()
    max_x = models.FloatField()
    max_y = models.FloatField()
    srs_code = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def bbox(self):
        return BBOX(self.min_x, self.min_y, self.max_x, self.max_y, self.srs_code)
```

Obviously this can lead to a lot of duplication of code if we need to add a set of fields to every model that can have a BBOX. This can make it hard to maintain and hard to change.

What's the best way to handle something like this? I thought of essentially creating a new table for BBOX:

```
class DjangoBbox(Model):

    min_x = models.FloatField()
    min_y = models.FloatField()
    max_x = models.FloatField()
    max_y = models.FloatField()
    srs_code = models.IntegerField()
```

Then I could add foreign key references where needed, but something about this idea smells to me. Is there something inherently wrong with this idea? The first thing I can think of is that theoretically multiple keys could point to the same DjangoBbox entry, and changes to one would reflect in both even if unintended.

Comment: You could create an abstract BBox base class that you inherit from each time you create a model that is a BBox with additional fields. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes). Or you could create a BBox mixin that covers all the properties and helpers, and inherit your BBox models from this mixin and `Model` (`class Layer(BboxMixin, PolymorphicModel)`). But then you'd still need to add the appropriate fields each time. I think abstract base model would work best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three options to tackle this:

1. Use an [abstract model class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes): You could create an abstract BBox base class that you inherit from each time you create a model. Just add the additional fields to your subclasses. So assuming an abstract `BBOXModel` class:

   ```
   class Layer(BBOXModel):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
       title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
       parent_layer = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)

   layer = Layer.objects.first()
   layer.min_x  # returns the min_x field
   layer.bbox  # returns the bbox property from `BBOXModel`
   layer.bbox = myBbox  # if you also create a setter for this property
   ```
2. [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) might also work, so that your models inherit from a concrete BBox Model: This automatically creates one-to-one relationships. It also creates one separate table with all your bounding boxes (so you can query it separately), but each one is attached to just one sub-model instance, that can be of different types. Also here all properties and methods on the parent class work just like you expect on the sub-classes. The code example from above is the same, except since you now have a concrete `BBOXModel` you can also do:

   ```
   bbox = BBOXModel.objects.first()
   bbox.layer  # works if this bbox "is part of a" Layer, otherwise it will throw an AttributeError
   ```
3. Finally, you could create a fully [custom field type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-model-fields/): It could hold a proper `BBOX` in your models: the field itself would be the `BBOX` you already have, so when saying `layer.bbox` this would be a full python `BBOX` object as you already are used to. It requires deciding how to encode a `BBOX` in the database. The example given in the link (a Hand of cards) might help. Personally, if using PostgreSQL, I would use a `JSONField` as underlying db field (inherit from `JSONField`). You'd probably only need to define `to_python` and `get_prep_value`, converting to and from JSON and calling `super()` to let the `JSONField` handle how it's represented in the db. So you'd be able to define your class like this:

   ```
   class Layer(PolymorphicModel):
       name = ...
       ...
       bbox = BBOXField()
   ```

With all three options, you can entirely re-use the `BBOX` class you already have by encapsulating handling of `BBOX` objects inside the classes (or the field). You should end up being able to just assign a `BBOX` to your model instance and when fetching a model instance from db, get its `bbox` property that would return the `BBOX`.